# Any experience with SSLMatic certificates?

Tags: ssl-certificate

SSLMatic certificates are very cheap. They sell RapidSSL certificates for $20. On RapidSSL website same certificate costs $80. How is that possible? Is it legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [GoDaddy's standard vs premium certificates](http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx). They're a bit different. the standard ones actually go down to $28/year + you can get another 15% off with promo codes. $20 isn't too out of the norm.

Comment: They also have a 25% discount if you're buying two certificates.